# Javascript array with default values (equivalent of Python's defaultdict)?

Tags: javascript, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set undefined javascript property before read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503666/set-undefined-javascript-property-before-read)

Is there an equivalent of [Python's defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in Javascript? This would be a Javascript array where the value returned for a missing key is definable. Something like:

```
var a = defaultArray("0");
console.log(a['dog']);
// would print 0
```

If not, how would you implement it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies

Comment: Bergi and rambo, thanks, but I don't think either of those do what I'm looking for. I'm not looking to implement a.get('dog') - I'm looking for a['dog'] to return some default value. That way the code that uses the array can treat it as a regular array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible in JavaScript. Btw, you certainly meant *Objects* (property-value-maps) instead of arrays. Two solutions:

- Implement your object as a [`Proxy`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies), which is designed to do exactly what you want. Yet, it is only a draft and currently only [supported in Firefox' Javascript 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).
- Use a getter function with a string parameter instead of object properties. That function can look up the input key in an internal "dictionary" object, and handle misses programmatically - e.g. creating values dynamically or returning default values.

  Of course you could build a factory for such getter functions.

```
function defaultDict(map, default) {
    return function(key) {
        if (key in map)
            return map[key];
        if (typeof default == "function")
            return default(key);
        return default;
    };
}

var a = defaultDict({cat: 1}, 0);
console.log(a('cat')); // 1
console.log(a('dog')); // 0
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi. That's too bad, I was really hoping there was an equivalent.

Comment: With some extension in the code to add new values, you will have same functionality that collections.defaultdict py.

Comment: I did what @Luchux is talking about in [pycollections.js](http://github.com/seriesoftubes/pycollections.js).