# How can I throw an error when accessing an object key that doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, object

This one's a long shot...

In Javascript, I was accessing an object attribute that I was certain existed, but I had a typo was in the name of the key, so was returning `undefined` and creating a bug.

How can I write code equivalent to the following, but that throws an error because the key does not exist?

```
var obj = {'myKey': 'myVal'},
    val = obj.myKye;
```

I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't require me writing a wrapper function that I use every time I want to access a member of an object. Is it possible? Is there another, 'stricter' technique in Javascript for accessing object attributes?

Comment: Are you trying to creating object or get the value form object..and your object formate is wrong..check it..

Comment: There's a syntax error with your closing brace while creating `obj`, should be `}` and not `)`

Comment: may be using `prototype` helps.

Comment: related: [Set undefined javascript property before read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503666/set-undefined-javascript-property-before-read)

Comment: You may try and see if ['strict mode'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) saves you from some errors...

Comment: You can accept any one of the answers from which you got solution...

Comment: The zealit node package can help you achieve this https://www.npmjs.com/package/zealit

Comment: object-fetch solves this issue as well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-fetch

Answer (score 3):

You can't...

If you want to be very careful [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) will let you check if property is defined.

```
function GetSafe(obj, propertyName)
{
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) return obj[propertyName];
   return "Unknown property:"+ propertyName; // throw or some other error reporting.
}
var obj = {'myKey': 'myVal'};
alert(GetSafe(obj, "myKey"));
alert(GetSafe(obj, "myKye"));
```

Comment: If you want to be very very careful, you would use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, propertyName)` :-)

Comment: @Bergi :) also if I would want to be that careful I'd use Script#

Answer (score 3):

> a solution that doesn't require me writing a wrapper function that I use every time I want to access a member of an object. Is it possible? Is there another, 'stricter' technique in Javascript for accessing object attributes?

No. You could use a [`Proxy`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproxies), which is designed to do exactly what you want. Yet, it is only a draft and currently only [supported in Firefox' Javascript 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) (FF18+).

There is no other possibility to have an implicit getter function for all property accesses. You will have to code it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function invalidKeyException(message) {
   this.message = message;
   this.name = "invalidKeyException";
}

var obj = {'myKey': 'myVal'},
val = obj.myKye;
if (val == undefined)
    throw new invalidKeyException("Key does not exist.");
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/r2MM4/

(Look at the console)

Comment: Try `obj = {"myKey":undefined}`...

Answer (score 0):

You can try these ways:

1) Using `typeof`:

```
try {
    var obj = {'myKey': 'myVal'}, val;

   if(typeof (obj.myKye) === 'undefined')
   {
      var e = new NotImplementedError("NotImplementedError Your_message");
      throw e;
   } 
   else
   {
     val = obj.myKye;
   }    
    alert(val);
   }
catch(e) 
  {
    alert(e);
  }
```

2) Using `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)`:

```
try {
    var obj = {'myKey': 'myVal'}, val;

   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(myKye))
   {
     val = obj.myKye;
   } 
   else
   {
      throw 'Property undefined';
   }
    alert(val);
   }
catch(e) 
  {
    alert(e);
  }
```

Comment: This is not completely correct - "undefined" is possible value (rare, but still): `obj={"myKey":undefined }` is valid object with `myKey` property.

Comment: :) it is exactly the same as before - `typeof(undefined)==="undefined"`, just longer. Side note `===` is better if you know that types must match (as in case of `typeof`).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov What is issue with `obj={"Key1":undefined }` and `typeof (obj.Key1) === 'undefined'`? doesn't it work fine?

Comment: It does - also you can't check that property is not there this way  - your recent edit to use `hasOwnProperty` should indicate that property is present, but value is `undefined`, unlike property not present at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `try-catch`, `hasOwnProperty` and create a [ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError).

```
var obj = {
        'myKey': 'myVal'
}, val;

try {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(myKye))
    {
        val = obj.myKye;
        alert(val);
    }

    else{
        var ex =  new ReferenceError()
    }
}
catch(ex) {
    alert(ex);
}
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/57nPY/8/)

**UPDATE:**

`obj.myKye` returns `undefined` and doesn't throw an exception because,

> That's the JS language specification.

[Objects return undefined for undefined property names](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.6.2.1), but [undefined variable references throw an error](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.7.1)

Comment: Not sure I follow this - The whole problem is that referencing obj.myKye *doesn't* throw an error. I'm trying to get it to throw an error, not handle errors.

Comment: Because that's the `JS` language specification. Objects return undefined for undefined property names, but undefined variable references throw an error.

Comment: The OP asked for "how to throw an exception from this", and when you say "*you can use a catch statement*" this neither is correct nor answers the question. You fixed that now by giving the "it's impossible" answer, but the first is still wrong. Btw, you should not use the ES3 reference any more

Comment: The downvote wasn't from me, but I imagine it's because the answer just doesn't apply to the question.