# Nested defaultdict of defaultdict

Tags: python, recursion, defaultdict, autovivification

Is there a way to make a defaultdict also be the default for the defaultdict? (i.e. infinite-level recursive defaultdict?)

I want to be able to do:

```
x = defaultdict(...stuff...)
x[0][1][0]
{}
```

So, I can do `x = defaultdict(defaultdict)`, but that's only a second level:

```
x[0]
{}
x[0][0]
KeyError: 0
```

There are recipes that can do this. But can it be done simply just using the normal defaultdict arguments?

Note this is asking how to do an infinite-level recursive defaultdict, so it's distinct to *[Python: defaultdict of defaultdict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029934)*, which was how to do a two-level defaultdict.

I'll probably just end up using the *bunch* pattern, but when I realized I didn't know how to do this, it got me interested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: defaultdict of defaultdict?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029934/python-defaultdict-of-defaultdict)

Comment: Not really... added info to the question to indicate why. Though that is a useful question.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

For an arbitrary number of levels:

```
def rec_dd():
    return defaultdict(rec_dd)

>>> x = rec_dd()
>>> x['a']['b']['c']['d']
defaultdict(<function rec_dd at 0x7f0dcef81500>, {})
>>> print json.dumps(x)
{"a": {"b": {"c": {"d": {}}}}}
```

Of course you could also do this with a lambda, but I find lambdas to be less readable.  In any case it would look like this:

```
rec_dd = lambda: defaultdict(rec_dd)
```

Comment: Indeed a perfect example, thanks. Could you please extend it to the case, that the data are loaded from json into defaultdict of defaultdict?

Comment: One note. If you are trying to use this code while pickling `lambda` won't work.

Comment: How can we define the type of the last value at the bottom of the dictionary?

Comment: Know this is old, but hope someone replies. How would you properly ad type hints to the rec_dd function?

Answer (score 324):

The other answers here tell you how to create a `defaultdict` which contains "infinitely many" `defaultdict`, but they fail to address what I think may have been your initial need which was to simply have a two-depth defaultdict.

You may have been looking for:

```
defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
```

The reasons why you might prefer this construct are:

- It is more explicit than the recursive solution, and therefore likely more understandable to the reader.
- This enables the "leaf" of the `defaultdict` to be something other than a dictionary, e.g.,: `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))` or `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))`

Comment: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list)) The correct form ?

Comment: Ooops, yes, the `lambda` form is correct--because the `defaultdict(something)` returns a dictionary-like object, but `defaultdict` expects a callable! Thank you!

Comment: This got marked as a possible duplicate of another question... but it wasn't my original question. I knew how to create a two-level defaultdict; what I didn't know was how to make it recursive. This answer is, in fact, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029934/python-defaultdict-of-defaultdict

Comment: One draw back of the lambda approach is that the objects it generates can't be pickled... but you can get around this by casting to a regular `dict(result)` before the pickle

Comment: This seems to only work for recursion levels greater than 1. For example `nested_dict['foo']['bar'].append('baz')` works, but `nested_dict['foo'].append('bar')` fails because the `defaultdict` class has no `append` attribute

Comment: @AddisonKlinke, I'm guessing you defined `nested_dict` as `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`, for which `nested_dict['foo']` is a `defaultdict(list)` which does not have an `append` attribute, but `nested_dict['foo']['bar']` is a `list` which *does* have an `append` attribute. Meanwhile, if you had defined `nested_dict` as `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))`, then `nested_dict['foo']['bar']` is a `dict` which does not have an `append` attribute.

Comment: @CpILL: For the fixed-level case, this is easily fixed by using `defaultdict(defaultdict(dict).copy)` instead. No need to convert back to `dict`, because the bound method of the template `defaultdict` *is* pickleable, unlike `lambda`s.

Answer (score 88):

There is a nifty trick for doing that:

```
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
```

Then you can create your `x` with `x = tree()`.

Comment: coming back to this, i think this is a piece of code i use more than any other :)

Answer (score 23):

Similar to BrenBarn's solution, but doesn't contain the name of the variable `tree` twice, so it works even after changes to the variable dictionary:

```
tree = (lambda f: f(f))(lambda a: (lambda: defaultdict(a(a))))
```

Then you can create each new `x` with `x = tree()`.

---

For the `def` version, we can use function closure scope to protect the data structure from the flaw where existing instances stop working if the `tree` name is rebound.  It looks like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def tree():
    def the_tree():
        return defaultdict(the_tree)
    return the_tree()
```

Comment: i'll have to think about this one (it's a little more complex). but i think your point is that if do x = tree(), but then someone comes by later and does tree=None, this one would still work, and that would wouldn't?

Answer (score 23):

I would also propose more OOP-styled implementation, which supports infinite nesting as well as properly formatted `repr`.

```
class NestedDefaultDict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NestedDefaultDict, self).__init__(NestedDefaultDict, *args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(dict(self))
```

Usage:

```
my_dict = NestedDefaultDict()
my_dict['a']['b'] = 1
my_dict['a']['c']['d'] = 2
my_dict['b']

print(my_dict)  # {'a': {'b': 1, 'c': {'d': 2}}, 'b': {}}
```

Comment: Neat ! I added the passthrough of `*args` and `**kwargs` which allows it to function like the `defaultdict`, namely to create a dict with keyword arguments. This is useful for passing `NestedDefaultDict` into `json.load`

Comment: Trying `my_dict = NestedDefaultDict(list)` returns a `TypeError` - is the `*args` intended to allow the leaf type definition in that way?

Comment: @AddisonKlinke No, in this implementation it's not. The `default_factory` argument is already taken by `NestedDefaultDict` type. There is no easy way to check if current node is leaf or not without building more complex class. However, you can write something like `my_dict['a']['b'][0]` to imitate node with list type.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer does not appear to support multiprocessing.

Comment: I like this! However, it doesn't support increment or list append:
`my_dict['a']['b'] += 1`
...will fail. Is there any way to get it to support the remaining dict operations?

Answer (score 1):

I based this of Andrew's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19189356/4084776) here.
If you are looking to load data from a json or an existing dict into the nester defaultdict see this example:

```py
def nested_defaultdict(existing=None, **kwargs):
    if existing is None:
        existing = {}
    if not isinstance(existing, dict):
        return existing
    existing = {key: nested_defaultdict(val) for key, val in existing.items()}
    return defaultdict(nested_defaultdict, existing, **kwargs)
```

https://gist.github.com/nucklehead/2d29628bb49115f3c30e78c071207775

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function for an arbitrary base defaultdict for an arbitrary depth of nesting.

(cross posting from [Can't pickle defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439301/cant-pickle-defaultdict/68397392#68397392))

```
def wrap_defaultdict(instance, times=1):
    """Wrap an instance an arbitrary number of `times` to create nested defaultdict.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    instance - list, dict, int, collections.Counter
    times - the number of nested keys above `instance`; if `times=3` dd[one][two][three] = instance
    
    Notes
    -----
    using `x.copy` allows pickling (loading to ipyparallel cluster or pkldump)
        - thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439301/cant-pickle-defaultdict
    """
    from collections import defaultdict

    def _dd(x):
        return defaultdict(x.copy)

    dd = defaultdict(instance)
    for i in range(times-1):
        dd = _dd(dd)

    return dd
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a recursive function to convert a recursive default dict to a normal dict

```
def defdict_to_dict(defdict, finaldict):
    # pass in an empty dict for finaldict
    for k, v in defdict.items():
        if isinstance(v, defaultdict):
            # new level created and that is the new value
            finaldict[k] = defdict_to_dict(v, {})
        else:
            finaldict[k] = v
    return finaldict

defdict_to_dict(my_rec_default_dict, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

@nucklehead's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62438324/9209968) can be extended to handle arrays in JSON as well:

```
def nested_dict(existing=None, **kwargs):
    if existing is None:
        existing = defaultdict()
    if isinstance(existing, list):
        existing = [nested_dict(val) for val in existing]
    if not isinstance(existing, dict):
        return existing
    existing = {key: nested_dict(val) for key, val in existing.items()}
    return defaultdict(nested_dict, existing, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Chris W answer, however, to address the type annotation concern, you could make it a factory function that defines the detailed types. For example this is the final solution to my problem when I was researching this question:

```
def frequency_map_factory() -> dict[str, dict[str, int]]:
    """
    Provides a recorder of: per X:str, frequency of Y:str occurrences.
    """
    return defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution similar to @Stanislav's answer that works with multiprocessing and also allows for termination of the nesting:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial

class NestedDD(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, n, *args, **kwargs):
        self.n = n
        factory = partial(build_nested_dd, n=n - 1) if n > 1 else int
        super().__init__(factory, *args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(dict(self))

def build_nested_dd(n):
    return NestedDD(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution similar to @Chris W., that makes more levels possible. It still allows the 'leaf' to be specified as something besides defaultdict.

Instead of a lambda, a closure is defined.

You might prefer this method because,

- the declaration of the nested defaultdict is written as nested functions so it might read easier.
- More than two levels are possible.
- The last leaf can be: list, set, ...

Here is an example.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

def another_defaultdict(factory):
    'return another layer of defaultdict as a factory function'
    def layer():
        return defaultdict(factory)  
    return layer




>>> # two levels
>>> d = defaultdict(another_defaultdict(list))

>>> # three levels
>>> d = defaultdict(another_defaultdict(another_defaultdict(list)))


>>> d['Canada']['Alberta'] = ['Calgary', 'Magrath', 'Cardston', 'Lethbridge']
>>> d['France']['Nord'] = ['Dunkirk', 'Croix']
>>> print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
{
  "Canada": {
    "Alberta": [
      "Calgary",
      "Magrath",
      "Cardston",
      "Lethbridge"
    ]
  },
  "France": {
    "Nord": [
      "Dunkirk",
      "Croix"
    ]
  }
}
```