# Create nested dictionary with predefined keys but without values in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key-value

#### Aim

For an assignment I need to put some **building information** (*geometries* and their *properties*) into a **GeoJSON** data structure.

#### Approach

My general approach is as follows:
create an empty dictionary with the necessary GeoJSON data structure and `.append` the data to this structure
(see: below)

```
output_buildings = {
    'type': "FeatureCollection",
    'features': [
    {
        'type': "Feature",
        'geometry': {
            'type': ,
            'coordinates': 
        },
        'properties': {
            'building_id': ,
            'building_year': ,
            'building_status': ,
            'building_occurance': 
        }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Issue

I know how to create a simple empty dictionary, but my problem is that *I don't know how to create a key structure **without values*** (as I want to append those values later on). I receive an error at `type` (the second one within `features`) at the `,`.

#### Previous efforts

- I found this topic on StackOverflow:
  [Method for Creating a Nested Dictionary from a List of Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387042/method-for-creating-a-nested-dictionary-from-a-list-of-keys);
  but it doesn't fit my purpose.
- I searched in the python docs with terms like "create empty nested dictionary", "create dictionary with empty values", but didn't find what I was looking for.
- I tried to use placeholders (%s / %d), but they are not suitable for this purpose
- Finally I tried to use `pass` (didn't work).

#### Question

I haven't found a solution yet. Can you please provide me with some suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using `None` as placeholders?

Comment: No such thing as having a key without a value in a dictionary, nor an empty variable. They're matched pairs. You can use placeholders, such as `None`, `float('NaN')` or a new object. The closest thing we have is having an uninitialized object attribute slot.

Comment: No, didn't consider `None`. I was looking for something like that. Can `None` be overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current dictionary structure is invalid, since you must have key-value pairs existent.

You can get around this by filling in `None` placeholders for keys that don't have a designated value. The key `coordinates` can be set to an empty list however, since you can have multiple coordinates.

**Valid GeoJSON structure:**

```
output_buildings = {
    'type': "FeatureCollection",
    'features': [
        {
            'type': "Feature",
            'geometry': {
                'type': None,
                'coordinates': []
            },
            'properties': {
                'building_id': None,
                'building_year': None,
                'building_status': None,
                'building_occurance': None
            }
        }
    ]
}
```