# Creating dictionary using list/tuple elements as key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples

I need to generate a dictionary like this:

```
{
  'newEnv': {
     'newProj': {
        'newComp': {
           'instances': [],
           'n_thing': 'newThing'
        }
     }
  }
}
```

from a tuple, like this: `('newEnv','newProj','newComp','newThing')` but only if that doesn't already exists. So, I tried this:

```
myDict = {}
(env,proj,comp,thing) = ('newEnv','newProj','newComp','newThing')

if env not in myDict:
    myDict[env] = {}
if proj not in myDict[env]:
    myDict[env][proj] = {}
if comp not in myDict[env][proj]:
    myDict[env][proj][comp] = {'n_thing': thing, 'instances': []}
```

which is pretty much working but not sure how efficient is that or if I should be doing this way at all. Any suggestion(s)??

Comment: By the way, your solution is not bad by any means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a loop (with just the first 3 keys, `newThing` is not a key in the chain):

```
myDict = {}
path = ('newEnv','newProj','newComp')
current = myDict
for key in path:
    current = current.setdefault(key, {})
```

where `current` ends up as the innermost dictionary, letting you set the `'n_thing'` and `'instances'` keys on that.

You could use `reduce()` to collapse that into a one-liner:

```
myDict = {}
path = ('newEnv','newProj','newComp')
reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}), path, myDict)
```

The `reduce` call returns the innermost dictionary, so you can use that to assign your final value:

```
myDict = {}
path = ('newEnv','newProj','newComp')
inner = reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}), path, myDict)
inner.update({'n_thing': 'newThing', 'instances': []})
```

Comment: `current = myDict.setdefault(key, {})` should be `current = current.setdefault(key, {}`

Comment: @MartijnPieters: that's really cool! worked just fine in the console, let me try in my original script.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: there is a slight problem implementing this in my script. I run this inside a for loop: `for queue in get_all_queues:` and for the `'instances': []` bit, I do this: `myDict[env][proj][comp]['instances'].append(queue)` to populate the 'instances' list after the last `if` statement. With new script, it's not being appended to the list but having only the last one. Looks like it's because of `inner.update()`? How to I fix that? Cheers!!

Comment: Yes, the update would replace the key; use `inner.setdefault('instances', []).append(queue)` (and set the other key with straight assignment).

Answer (score 0):

you can do something similar, maybe slightly simpler, with a defaultdict of defaultdicts (see [defaultdict of defaultdict, nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189274/defaultdict-of-defaultdict-nested) for some discussion)

```
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)

base = tree()
for x in mytuple[:-2]:
    base = base[x]
base[x] = mytuple[-1]
```

which is very similar to martijn's, just using the default functionality to create the subdicts instead of doing it directly with `setdefault`.

this also lets you type directly

```
myDict[env][proj][comp].setdefault('instances', list()).append(queue)
```

if that's what you are really looking for. (there's no way to remove the setdefault unfortunately; after all, I don't know ahead of time whether you want a list or dict. you only have one default)....

Comment: That's a nice solution too but I've accepted martijn's as it's going very well with the rest of the script. thanks for showing the different route. Cheers!!