# Pandas to D3. Serializing dataframes to JSON

Tags: python, json, d3.js, pandas

I have a DataFrame with the following columns and no duplicates:

```
['region', 'type', 'name', 'value']
```

that can be seen as a hierarchy as follows

```
grouped = df.groupby(['region','type', 'name'])
```

I would like to serialize this hierarchy as a JSON object.

If anyone is interested, the motivation behind this is to eventually put together a visualization like [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582) which requires a `JSON` file.

To do so, I need to convert `grouped` into the following:

```
new_data['children'][i]['name'] = region
new_data['children'][i]['children'][j]['name'] = type
new_data['children'][i]['children'][j]'children'][k]['name'] = name
new_data['children'][i]['children'][j]'children'][k]['size'] = value
...
```

where `region`, `type`, `name` correspond to different levels of the hierarchy (indexed by `i`, `j` and `k`)

Is there an easy way in Pandas/Python to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines might get you there.

```
from collections import defaultdict

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)  # a recursive defaultdict
d = tree()
for _, (region, type, name, value) in df.iterrows():
    d['children'][region]['name'] = region
    ...

json.dumps(d)
```

A vectorized solution would be better, and maybe something that takes advantage of the speed of groupby, but I can't think of such a solution.

Also take a look at `df.groupby(...).groups`, which return a dict.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19189366/1221924).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another script to take a pandas df and output a flare.json file: https://github.com/andrewheekin/csv2flare.json