# Creating a flare json to be used in D3 from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, flare

I have a dataframe that I want to convert to a hierarchical flare json to be used in a D3 visulalization like this: [D3 sunburst](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst)

My dataframe contains a hierarchial data such as this:

[image]

And the output I want should look like this:

```
{"name": "flare","children": 
    [
        {"name": "Animal", "children": 
            [
                {"name": "Mammal", "children":
                    [
                        {"name": "Fox","value":35000}, 
                        {"name": "Lion","value":25000}
                    ]
                },
                {"name": "Fish", "children":
                    [
                        {"name": "Cod","value":35000} 
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {"name": "Plant", "children": 
            [
                {"name": "Tree", "children":
                    [
                        {"name": "Oak","value":35000} 
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
}
```

I have tried several approaches, but cant get it right. Here is my non-working code, inspired by this post: [Pandas to D3. Serializing dataframes to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531145/pandas-to-d3-serializing-dataframes-to-json)

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'group1':["Animal", "Animal", "Animal", "Plant"],'group2':["Mammal", "Mammal", "Fish", "Tree"], 'group3':["Fox", "Lion", "Cod", "Oak"],'value':[35000,25000,15000,1500]  })
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)  
d = tree()
for _, (group0,group1, group2, group3, value) in df.iterrows():
    d['name'][group0]['children'] = group1
    d['name'][group1]['children'] = group2
    d['name'][group2]['children'] = group3
    d['name'][group3]['children'] = value


json.dumps(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar visualization project that requires moving data from a Pandas DataFrame to a JSON file that works with D3.

I came across your post while looking for a solution and ended up writing something based on this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/andrewheekin/csv2flare.json/blob/master/csv2flare.json.py) and with input from the link you provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531145/pandas-to-d3-serializing-dataframes-to-json).

The code is not pretty and is a bit hacky and slow. But based on my project, it seems to work just fine for any amount of data as long as it has three levels and a value field. You should be able to simply fork the [D3 Starburst notebook](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst) and replace the flare.json file with this code's output.

The modification that I made here, based on the original GitHub post, is to provide consideration for three levels of data. So, if the name of the level 0 node exists, then append from level 1 and on. Likewise, if the name of the level 1 node exists, then append the level 2 node (*the third level*). Otherwise, append the full path of data. If you need more, some kind of recursion might do the trick, or just keep hacking it to add more levels

```python
# code snip to format Pandas DataFrame to json for D3 Starburst Chart

# libraries
import json
import pandas as pd

# example data with three levels and a single value field
data = {'group1': ['Animal', 'Animal', 'Animal', 'Plant'],
        'group2': ['Mammal', 'Mammal', 'Fish', 'Tree'],
        'group3': ['Fox', 'Lion', 'Cod', 'Oak'],
        'value': [35000, 25000, 15000, 1500]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

print(df)

""" The sample dataframe
group1  group2 group3  value
0  Animal  Mammal    Fox  35000
1  Animal  Mammal   Lion  25000
2  Animal    Fish    Cod  15000
3   Plant    Tree    Oak   1500
"""

# initialize a flare dictionary
flare = {"name": "flare", "children": []}

# iterate through dataframe values
for row in df.values:
    level0 = row[0]
    level1 = row[1]
    level2 = row[2]
    value = row[3]
    
    # create a dictionary with all the row data
    d = {'name': level0,
          'children': [{'name': level1,
                        'children': [{'name': level2,
                                      'value': value}]}]}
    # initialize key lists
    key0 = []
    key1 = []

    # iterate through first level node names
    for i in flare['children']:
        key0.append(i['name'])

        # iterate through next level node names
        key1 = []
        for _, v in i.items():
            if isinstance(v, list):
                for x in v:
                    key1.append(x['name'])

    # add the full row of data if the root is not in key0
    if level0 not in key0:
        d = {'name': level0,
              'children': [{'name': level1,
                            'children': [{'name': level2,
                                          'value': value}]}]}
        flare['children'].append(d)

    elif level1 not in key1:

        # if the root exists, then append only the next level children

        d = {'name': level1,
              'children': [{'name': level2,
                            'value': value}]}

        flare['children'][key0.index(level0)]['children'].append(d)

    else:

        # if the root exists, then only append the next level children
        
        d = {'name': level2,
             'value': value}

        flare['children'][key0.index(level0)]['children'][key1.index(level1)]['children'].append(d)

# uncomment next three lines to save as json file
# save to some file
# with open('filename_here.json', 'w') as outfile:
#     json.dump(flare, outfile)

print(json.dumps(flare, indent=2))

""" the expected output of this json data
{
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Animal",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Mammal",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Fox",
              "value": 35000
            },
            {
              "name": "Lion",
              "value1": 25000
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Fish",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Cod",
              "value": 15000
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Plant",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Tree",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Oak",
              "value": 1500
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
"""
```