# Trouble with "multi-dimensional" dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.4

I'm trying to create the following data structure on the fly by reading the output of another script line by line, if certain combinations of thresholds are breached, I want to track those in a dictionary:

```
data = {}

data[device]['mntpt']   = mntpt
data[device][timestamp] = { 'r_ops': r_ops, 'r_avgrtt': r_avgrtt, 'r_avgexe': r_avgexe, 'w_ops': w_ops, 'w_avgrtt': w_avgrtt, 'w_avgexe': w_avgexe }
```

For each device, there can be a varying number of timestamps, each containing 6 datapoints. The r_xxx and w_xxx variables are floats. device, mntpt and timestamp are strings.

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsubscriptable object
```

I get the same error if I comment out this line:

```
# data[device]['mntpt']   = mntpt
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thx

Comment: What is the value at the key ``device``? If it's not a dict, what you're trying to do won't work. You should probably look into the [``deafultdict``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `data = {}` and then `data[x][y] = z`, python is yelling at you because you haven't told it what `data[x]` is yet, so it doesn't know how to subscript it with `y`

You should say:

```
data = {}
data[device] = {}
data[device]['mntpnt'] = mntpnt
data[device][timestamp] = {stuff}
```

Then you've let python know in advance that it's an empty dict, and it knows how to subscript a dict.

Comment: Awesome thx... been writing perl for so long, it actually lets you do sloppy stuff like that. =)

Answer (score 1):

`genisage` has a working solution. [You can also use a `defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects)

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(dict)

data[device]['mntpt']   = mntpt
data[device][timestamp] = { 'r_ops': r_ops, 'r_avgrtt': r_avgrtt, 'r_avgexe': r_avgexe, 'w_ops': w_ops, 'w_avgrtt': w_avgrtt, 'w_avgexe': w_avgexe }
```

The way this works is that if you try to assign to `data[device]`, but there's no dictionary defined there yet, it will automatically create one for you.

This also works with `list`, `int` etc. Here's a `list` example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

data[device].append(mntpt)
data[device].append({ 'r_ops': r_ops, 'r_avgrtt': r_avgrtt, 'r_avgexe': r_avgexe, 'w_ops': w_ops, 'w_avgrtt': w_avgrtt, 'w_avgexe': w_avgexe })
```

**EDIT:** This solution only works in Python 2.5 or newer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/19189356/1612701 for arbitrarily nested `defaultdict`s.