# initialize defaultdict in Python

Tags: python

A dumb question after searching for Python Doc, for the constructor of defaultdict, there is only one parameter, which is type of value. Is there a way to specify type of key? I read a few samples and it seems no one specify type of key, and they just specify type of value. And whether it is needed or not -- interested to learn why defaultdict just needs to specify type of value.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: What would a default key be? How would you access a default key?

Comment: @AChampion, thanks for the reply. I do not get your points, what do you mean default key? Do you mean default value?

Comment: @AChampion, thanks for the clarification. If you could add a reply, I will mark it as answered to benefit more people. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you're not specifying the "type" of the values. You're specifying a no-argument constructor, which must construct a default value. For instance, see this answer for a way to create an indefinitely nested defaultdict: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19189356/2337736 Or, for a trivial example, `fives = defaultdict(lambda : 5)` will product a `defaultdict` where the default value is 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is a dynamically typed language, your don't specify types (ignoring the newly added type hints). The argument to defaultdict is a function that returns a value when accessing a key that hasn't been added to the dictionary. Not a type

```
defaultdict(int)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
defaultdict(lambda:int())   # int() returns 0
```

Comment: Thanks AChampion for all the help, mark your reply as answer. :)