# Mongoengine is very slow on large documents compared to native pymongo usage

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have the following mongoengine model:

```
class MyModel(Document):
    date        = DateTimeField(required = True)
    data_dict_1 = DictField(required = False)
    data_dict_2 = DictField(required = True)
```

In some cases the document in the DB can be very large (around 5-10MB), and the data_dict fields contain complex nested documents (dict of lists of dicts, etc...).

I have encountered two (possibly related) issues:

1. When I run native pymongo find_one() query, it returns within a second. When I run MyModel.objects.first() it takes 5-10 seconds.
2. When I query a single large document from the DB, and then access its field, it takes 10-20 seconds just to do the following:

   ```
   m = MyModel.objects.first()
   val = m.data_dict_1.get(some_key)
   ```

The data in the object does not contain any references to any other objects, so it is not an issue of objects dereferencing.
I suspect it is related to some inefficiency of the internal data representation of mongoengine, which affects the document object construction as well as fields access. Is there anything I can do to improve this ?

Comment: It seems there are 2 different things. Native method loads 1 document and stops, while mongoengine loads all documents and return first one. Try to change from `find_one()` to `list(db.collection.find())[0]` to equal methods.

Comment: I also tried adding limit(1) in the mongoengine query, it didn't help. Seems that most of the time is spent on building the mongoengine Document object, with all the nested objects..

Comment: `skip` and `limit` work once documents are loaded :( Try to filter by specific query... [http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#query-operators](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#query-operators)

Comment: I don't think this is correct  - from what i saw on the "explain" of the mongoengine query when using limit(1), it queries just a single document from mongo (the "explain" result is directly from mongo). So, in the same sense, it won't be correct to compare to list(db.collection.find())[0] - as this would load the entire collection's content into the memory - not something that mongoengine is doing.

Comment: `skip` and `limit` are **not** applied to loaded documents they are sent as query parameters.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**TL;DR: mongoengine is spending ages converting all the returned arrays to dicts**

To test this out I built a collection with a document with a `DictField` with a large nested `dict`. The doc being roughly in your 5-10MB range.

We can then use [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/timeit.html) to confirm the difference in reads using pymongo and mongoengine.

We can then use [pycallgraph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/en/master/index.html) and [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to see what is taking mongoengine so damn long.

Here is the code in full:

```
import datetime
import itertools
import random
import sys
import timeit
from collections import defaultdict

import mongoengine as db
from pycallgraph.output.graphviz import GraphvizOutput
from pycallgraph.pycallgraph import PyCallGraph

db.connect("test-dicts")


class MyModel(db.Document):
    date = db.DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.date.today)
    data_dict_1 = db.DictField(required=False)


MyModel.drop_collection()

data_1 = ['foo', 'bar']
data_2 = ['spam', 'eggs', 'ham']
data_3 = ["subf{}".format(f) for f in range(5)]

m = MyModel()
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)  # http://stackoverflow.com/a/19189366/3271558
data = tree()
for _d1, _d2, _d3 in itertools.product(data_1, data_2, data_3):
    data[_d1][_d2][_d3] = list(random.sample(range(50000), 20000))
m.data_dict_1 = data
m.save()


def pymongo_doc():
    return db.connection.get_connection()["test-dicts"]['my_model'].find_one()


def mongoengine_doc():
    return MyModel.objects.first()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("pymongo took {:2.2f}s".format(timeit.timeit(pymongo_doc, number=10)))
    print("mongoengine took", timeit.timeit(mongoengine_doc, number=10))
    with PyCallGraph(output=GraphvizOutput()):
        mongoengine_doc()
```

And the output proves that mongoengine is being very slow compared to pymongo:

```
pymongo took 0.87s
mongoengine took 25.81118331072267
```

The resulting call graph illustrates pretty clearly where the bottle neck is:

[image: pycallgraph.png for mongoengine read of large doc]
[image: hot spot in pycallgraph]

Essentially  mongoengine will call the to_python method on every `DictField` that it gets back from the db. `to_python` is pretty slow and in our example it's being called an insane number of times.

Mongoengine is used to elegantly map your document structure to python objects. If you have very large unstructured documents (which mongodb is great for) then mongoengine isn't really the right tool and you should just use pymongo.

However, if you know the structure you can use `EmbeddedDocument` fields to get slightly better performance from mongoengine. I've run a similar but not equivalent test [code in this gist](https://gist.github.com/BeardedSteve/a1484adcf7475f62028e) and the output is:

```
pymongo with dict took 0.12s
pymongo with embed took 0.12s
mongoengine with dict took 4.3059175412661075
mongoengine with embed took 1.1639373211854682
```

So you can make mongoengine faster but pymongo is much faster still.

**UPDATE**

A good shortcut to the pymongo interface here is to use the aggregation framework:

```
def mongoengine_agg_doc():
    return list(MyModel.objects.aggregate({"$limit":1}))[0]
```

Comment: Excellent analysis, thanks a lot ! (I should have done it myself !). I'm not sure that it's wise for mongoengine to hold all the embedded data in the DictField format, or at least have a way to avoid it. I have opened an issue on mongoengine's github, hope it will help: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1230

Comment: Thanks, yes it seems like you should be able to specify a field as a generic pymongo reference.

Comment: This is priceless. Thanks for sharing.