# Efficiently retrieve data (all in one batch ideally) with mongengine in Python 3

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Let's say I have class User which inherits from the Document class (I am using Mongoengine). Now, I want to retrieve all users signed up after some timestamp. Here is the method I am using:

```
def get_users(cls, start_timestamp):
    return cls.objects(ts__gte=start_timestamp)
```

1000 documents are returned in 3 seconds. This is extremely slow. I have done similar queries in SQL in a couple of miliseconds. I am new to MongoDB and No-SQL in general, so I guess I am doing something terribly wrong.

I suspect the retrieval is slow because it is done in several batches. I read somewhere that for PyMongo the batch size is 101, but I do not know if that is same for Mongoengine.

Can I change the batch size, so I could get all documents at once. I will know approximately how much data will be retrieved in total.

Any other suggestions are very welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggest there is no way that it should take 3 seconds to run this query. However, the issue is not going to be the performance of the pymongo driver, some things to consider:

- Make sure that the `ts` field is included in the [indexes](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.io/guide/defining-documents.html#indexes) for the user collection
- Mongoengine does some aggressive de-referencing so if the 1000 returned user documents have one or more `ReferenceField` then each of those results in additional queries. [There are ways to avoid this.](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.io/guide/querying.html#query-efficiency-and-performance)
- Mongoengine provides [a direct interface](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.io/guide/querying.html#aggregation) to the pymongo method for the [mongodb aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline) this is **by far the most efficient way to query mongodb**
- mongodb [recently released](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-announce/HWfqcK1T034) an official python ODM [pymodm](https://github.com/mongodb/pymodm) in part to provide better default performance than mongoengine

Comment: I have already improved the performance using direct interface to pymongo. It was really surprising how much the speed improved, going from 3 seconds to 300 miliseconds. Is there something wrong the way I am using Mongoengine in the code snippet in the question? I do not see any value in using Mongoengine if I need to write pymongo instead.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257305/mongoengine-is-very-slow-on-large-documents-comapred-to-native-pymongo-usage/35274930#35274930) may be part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the great answers!