# Loop creating nested dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-loops

I'm importing data from CSV and placing it in nested dicts.
My current key-checking looks like this:

```
data = {}
[...]
if day not in data:
    data[day] = {}
if hour not in data[day]:
    data[day][hour] = {}
if user in data[day][hour]:
    worked_time += (
        data[day][hour][user]['worked_time']
    )
data[day][hour][user] = {
    'name': users[user]['name'],
    'worked_time': worked_time
}
```

They can be several users for each `data[day][hour]`
Was wondering if there's better way for checking if each `key` exists than using several `ifs`.

Comment: I don't think `'name': [users][user]['name'],` is valid python syntax. But `collections.defaultdict` or `dict.setdefault` may be good alternatives to these `if xxx not in yyy` statements.

Comment: this should answer your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189274/defaultdict-of-defaultdict-nested#19189356

Comment: You're right sir, that's my misspelling, should be `users[user]['name]`. Will check linked answer, thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is nice.  If a dict doesn't have a value for the key you specify, it creates a new one for you.

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict)))
data['day']['hour']['user']['worked_time'] = 2
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, and your edited answer is way better than the first one.