# Using dictionary to store data (array) in multiple key groups

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I am trying to store arrays in multiple key groups to generate group-wise summaries. I thought `dict of dicts` may be a solution. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47104253/1247080) answer, I tried to make a dict of dict. Here is the code

```
import numpy
from collections import defaultdict

s1 = numpy.array([[1L, 'B', 4],
       [1L, 'A', 3],
       [1L, 'B', 10],
       [1L, 'A', 0.0],
       [2L, 'A', 11],
       [2L, 'B', 13],
       [2L, 'B', 1],
       [2L, 'A', 6]], dtype=object)

def make_dict():
    return defaultdict(make_dict)

d = defaultdict(make_dict)

for x in s1:
    d[x[0]][x[1]] = x[2]
```

So, `d[1]['B']` gives `10` while I was expecting `[4,10]`. Looks like d is picking up the last combination. Is there a way to append all the values that fit a particular key combination? I thought `defaultdict` should take care of this. Where am I going wrong? Is there any other solution to this? I can easily do it in `pandas` and I love the library. But I am requiring an non-`pandas` solution.

**Update**
The question was answered (@juanpa.arrivillaga ) but looks like my example data was inadequate. How about if we had the following as data?

```
s1 = numpy.array([
        [1L, 'B', 4,3],
        [1L, 'A', 3,5],
        [1L, 'B', 10,23],
        [2L, 'A', 11,1],
        [2L, 'B', 1,8],
        [2L, 'A', 6,23]
        ], dtype=object)
```

We may not be able to use `defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))` as the dictionary container. How to extend the solution to include and append 2D-array instead of list. I expect `d[1]['A']` should give me `[[3,5],[11,1]]`

Comment: Is there some particular reason you are using a numpy-array of strings? Why not a list? Why not just use pandas, because it seems you are re-implementing `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`

Comment: But what is `x`??? was that suppose to be `row`?

Comment: The problem is that `d[x[0]][x[1]] = x[2]` will always over-write the last value in the `defaultdict`. You probably want a default factory like `lambda:defaultdict(defaultdict(list))`. And then you'll need to do something like `d[x[0]][x[1]].append(x[2])` Will you always know the dimensions?

Comment: What would the ouput looks like in this case, then? What are you expecting?

Comment: I expect `[[3,5],[11,1]]` from d[1]['A']

Comment: Check out the edit. I assume you are on Python 2, though, so that syntax won't work, but I've provided the Python 2 version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using `numpy` - which, you really shouldn't for heterogeneous data-types, you should just use `pandas`:

```
In [8]: data = [[1, 'B', 4],
   ...:        [1, 'A', 3],
   ...:        [1, 'B', 10],
   ...:        [1, 'A', 0.0],
   ...:        [2, 'A', 11],
   ...:        [2, 'B', 13],
   ...:        [2, 'B', 1],
   ...:        [2, 'A', 6]]
In [9]: import pandas as pd

In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['c1','c2','c3'])

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   c1 c2    c3
0   1  B   4.0
1   1  A   3.0
2   1  B  10.0
3   1  A   0.0
4   2  A  11.0
5   2  B  13.0
6   2  B   1.0
7   2  A   6.0

In [12]: df.groupby(['c1','c2']).describe()
Out[12]:
         c3
      count mean       std  min   25%  50%    75%   max
c1 c2
1  A    2.0  1.5  2.121320  0.0  0.75  1.5   2.25   3.0
   B    2.0  7.0  4.242641  4.0  5.50  7.0   8.50  10.0
2  A    2.0  8.5  3.535534  6.0  7.25  8.5   9.75  11.0
   B    2.0  7.0  8.485281  1.0  4.00  7.0  10.00  13.0
```

If you must do this without `pandas`:

```
In [13]: from collections import defaultdict

In [14]: grouper = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))

In [15]: for c1,c2,c3 in data:
    ...:     grouper[c1][c2].append(c3)
    ...:

In [16]: grouper
Out[16]:
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {1: defaultdict(list, {'A': [3, 0.0], 'B': [4, 10]}),
             2: defaultdict(list, {'A': [11, 6], 'B': [13, 1]})})
In [17]: grouper[1]['B']
Out[17]: [4, 10]
```

If you are always going to be grouping on the first two columns, just do something like the following:

```
In [6]: grouper = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))

In [7]: for c1, c2, *rest in s1:
   ...:     grouper[c1][c2].append(rest)
   ...:

In [8]: grouper
Out[8]:
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {1: defaultdict(list, {'A': [[3, 5]], 'B': [[4, 3], [10, 23]]}),
             2: defaultdict(list, {'A': [[11, 1], [6, 23]], 'B': [[1, 8]]})})

In [9]: grouper[1]['A']
Out[9]: [[3, 5]]

In [10]: grouper[1]['B']
Out[10]: [[4, 3], [10, 23]]

In [11]: grouper[2]['B']
Out[11]: [[1, 8]]

In [12]: grouper[2]['A']
Out[12]: [[11, 1], [6, 23]]
```

For Python 2, you will have to modify a little bit, since it lacks support for iterable unpacking:

```
In [8]: for arr in s1:
   ...:     c1, c2 = arr[:2]
   ...:     rest = list(arr[2:])
   ...:     grouper[c1][c2].append(rest)
   ...:

In [9]: grouper
Out[9]:
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {1L: defaultdict(list, {'A': [[3, 5]], 'B': [[4, 3], [10, 23]]}),
             2L: defaultdict(list, {'A': [[11, 1], [6, 23]], 'B': [[1, 8]]})})
```

Comment: I know this can be done in `pandas`. But I want to avoid `pandas` for now. My final goal is to create an `exe` from the python file using pyinstaller and there is some issue with `pandas==0.21`. Also with `pandas` the final `exe` file becomes large.

Comment: @Stat-R well, as I noted in the comments, the issue is providing the correct default-factory. See my edit

Comment: Wow! I understand what  you are saying. *default-factory* is the key

Comment: How do we do it when the default-factory is a 2D array?

Comment: @Stat-R what do you mean? The default-factory is a *function* or callable, not an array...

Comment: Sorry. I mean instead of list how should we incorporate an 2D-array. Imagine `s1` in my example had more than 3 columns. Then grouper[1]['B'] would be an 2D array.

Comment: @Stat-R what exactly are you working with? Can you edit your question and be more specific? Again, why are you even using numpy arrays?