# Python: Defaultdict with Defaultdict as recursive default key

Tags: python, defaultdict

I am looking for a way to define a collections.defaultdict (factory) that returns for each key in arbitrary depth again a defaultdict.

E.g.,

```
  foo = collections.defaultdict(lambda: *magic with defaultdict* )
```

so that

```
>>>> foo['bar']
defaultdict(<function lambda --> defaultdict,...)
>>> foo['bar']['baz']
defaultdict(<function lambda --> defaultdict,...)
```

ad infinitum.

I tried something more baroque with a deepcopy of a lambda-defaultdict as lambda of the 'actual' defaultdict

```
>>> fooDict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict()))
>>> barDict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(lambda: copy.deepcopy(fooDict)))
```

but which fails miserably in the forth generation (not surprisingly, when thinking through).

Comment: hmmmm You could create class whichimplements `x.__getitem__(key)` and then when object under the `key` exists return it , when not just return new instance of this same class.

Comment: I went now for @BrenBarn answer 
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree) ; 
foo =  tree()
in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189274/defaultdict-of-defaultdict-nested