# don't understand this lambda expression with defaultdict

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, defaultdict

I saw this example at pythontips. I do not understand the second line when defaultdict takes an argument "tree" and return a "tree".

```
import collections
tree = lambda: collections.defaultdict(tree)
some_dict = tree()
some_dict['color']['favor'] = "yellow"
# Works fine
```

After I run this code, I checked the type of some_dict

```
defaultdict(< function < lambda > at 0x7f19ae634048 >, 
            {'color': defaultdict(
                  < function < lambda > at 0x7f19ae634048 >, {'favor': 'yellow'})})
```

Comment: btw the tip is from http://book.pythontips.com/en/testing/collections.html

Comment: It's a defaultdict of defacultdicts. It uses a recursive lambda function to generate a new empty defaultdict that itself will generate other defaultdicts when needed.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189274/defaultdict-of-defaultdict-nested (not exactly a duplicate, though)

Comment: This code is very clever. Perhaps too clever.

Comment: It's no more clever than any recursive function in Python. It's just using the name that the function currently being defined will be assigned to.

Comment: That recursive function is called inside `defaultdict`, which is why it's so clever.

Comment: @Gabriel How are you supposed to define a recursive data type without a recursive definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pretty clever way to create a recursive `defaultdict`. It's a little tricky to understand at first but once you dig into what's happening, it's actually a pretty simple use of recursion.

In this example, we define a recursive lambda function, `tree`, that returns a `defaultdict` whose constructor is `tree`. Let's rewrite this using regular functions for clarity.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

def get_recursive_dict():
    return defaultdict(get_recursive_dict)
```

Note that we're returning `defaultdict(get_recursive_dict)` and not `defaultdict(get_recursive_dict())`. We want to pass `defaultdict` a callable object (i.e. the function `get_recursive_dict`). Actually calling `get_recursive_dict()` would result in infinite recursion.

If we call `get_recursive_dict`, we get an empty `defaultdict` whose default value is the function `get_recursive_dict`.

```
recursive_dict = get_recursive_dict()
print(recursive_dict)
# defaultdict(<function get_recursive_dict at 0x0000000004FFC4A8>, {})
```

Let's see this in action. Create the key `'alice'` and it's corresponding value defaults to an empty `defaultdict` whose default value is the function `get_recursive_dict`. Notice that this is the same default value as our `recursive_dict`!

```
print(recursive_dict['alice'])
# defaultdict(<function get_recursive_dict at 0x0000000004AF46D8>, {})
print(recursive_dict)
# defaultdict(<function get_recursive_dict at 0x0000000004AF46D8>, {'alice': defaultdict(<function get_recursive_dict at 0x0000000004AF46D8>, {})})
```

So we can create as many nested dictionaries as we want.

```
recursive_dict['bob']['age'] = 2
recursive_dict['charlie']['food']['dessert'] = 'cake'
print(recursive_dict)
# defaultdict(<function get_recursive_dict at 0x00000000049BD4A8>, {'charlie': defaultdict(<function get_recursive_dict at 0x00000000049BD4A8>, {'food': defaultdict(<function get_recursive_dict at 0x00000000049BD4A8>, {'dessert': 'cake'})}), 'bob': defaultdict(<function get_recursive_dict at 0x00000000049BD4A8>, {'age': 2}), 'alice': defaultdict(<function get_recursive_dict at 0x00000000049BD4A8>, {})})
```

Once you overwrite the default value with a key, you can no longer create arbitrarily deep nested dictionaries.

```
recursive_dict['bob']['age']['year'] = 2016
# TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

I hope this clears things up!

Answer (score 3):

Two points to note:

1. `lambda` represents an anonymous function.
2. Functions are first-class objects in Python. They may be assigned to a variable like any other object.

So here are 2 different ways to define functionally identical objects. They are recursive functions because they reference themselves.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# anonymous
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)

# explicit
def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)
```

Running the final 2 lines with these different definitions in turn, you see only a subtle difference in the naming of the `defaultdict` type:

```
# anonymous
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
            {'color': defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
                         {'favor': 'yellow'})})

# explicit
defaultdict(<function __main__.tree()>,
            {'color': defaultdict(<function __main__.tree()>,
                         {'favor': 'yellow'})})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to see if you try this: `a = lambda: a`, you'll see that `a()` returns `a`. So...

```
>>> a = lambda: a
>>> a()()()()
<function <lambda> at 0x102bffd08>
```

They're doing this with the `defaultdict` too. `tree` is a function returning a defaultdict whose default value is yet another defaultdict, and so on.

I wasn't actually aware of this either. I thought `tree` would have to be defined first. Maybe it's a special Python rule? (EDIT:) No, I forgot that Python does the name lookup at runtime, and `tree` already points to the lambda then. In C++ there's compile-time reference checking, but you can define functions that reference themselves.

It seems like a way to create behavior that some users wouldn't expect. Like say you accidentally redefine `tree` later, your defaultdict is broken:

```
>>> import collections
>>> tree = lambda: collections.defaultdict(tree)
>>> some_dict = tree()
>>> tree = 4
>>> some_dict[4][3] = 2 # TypeError: first argument must be callable or None
```

Comment: It's not special; name lookups occur when a value is needed, and the value isn't needed until the function is *called*.

Comment: No special python rule. When the lambda is ran the `tree` is already defined.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So now you rely on `a` not changing. if you do `a = lambda: a` then `b = a` then `a = 3`, `b()` will return 3 now.