# Is there a python function like Clojure's get-in?

Tags: python, clojure

Is there something equivalent to Clojure's get-in function in Python? It gets the data at the given path in some data structure.

In Clojure it is used like:

```
(def employee
  {:name "John"
   :details {:email "info@domain.com"
             :phone "555-144-300"}})

(get-in employee [:details :email])  ; => "info@domain.com"
```

If translated to Python syntax it would be used like:

```
dictionary = {'a': {'b': 10}}
get_in(dictionary, ['a', 'b'])  # => 10
```

This function is used to access arbitrary data points in nestled data structures where the paths are not known at compile time, they are dynamic. More usage examples of `get-in` can be found on [clojuredocs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get-in).

Comment: maybe [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156144/get-value-from-dictionary-given-a-list-of-nested-keys) can help.

Comment: What's wrong with `dictionary['a']['b']` ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers The path is dynamic, known at run time.

Comment: @Rovanion then you may want to clarify your question and example code - in your example the path is hardcoded.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Added a short clearification and a link with further usage and documentation.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19189274/1435475) is a similar question, but the solution has the added benefit of being able to write the found object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write:

```
dictionary.get('details', {}).get('email')
```

This will safely get the value you need or `None`, without throwing an exception - just like Clojure's `get-in` does.

If you need a dedicated function for that, you can write:

```
def get_in(d, keys):
    if not keys:
        return d
    elif len(keys) == 1:
        return d.get(keys[0])
    else:
        return get_in(d.get(keys[0], {}), keys[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can certainly make one

```
def get_in(d, keys):
   if not keys:
       return d
   return get_in(d[keys[0]], keys[1:])
```

Comment: [A bit more complete version](https://utgwkk.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/11/14/144209) outside Stack Overflow... (blog is Japanese, but code is code)

Comment: @Amadan, Good one.

Comment: This will throw an exception if a key is missing - which is different from the Clojure behaviour.

Comment: @AlephAleph I saw your answer, didn't have to point it out here too... And in python we're a bit more happy to handle errors than in a functional language like closure. I'd rather get a `KeyError` than `None` which could be either a result or a fail. Let the user decide how they want to handle a fail.

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop should solve your problem -

```
x = {'a':{'b':{'c': 1}}}

def get_element(elements, dictionary):
    for i in elements:
        try:
            dictionary = dictionary[i]
        except KeyError:
            return False
    return dictionary

print(get_element(['a', 'b', 'c'], x))
# 1
print(get_element(['a', 'z', 'c'], x))
# False
```