# List append is overwriting my previous values

Tags: python

I'm trying to build dynamically a query for ElasticSearch, here is my code:

```
import json

query_string = "person human"

query = {}

query['query'] = {}
query['query']['bool']  = {}
query['query']['bool']['must']  = {}

must_string = []
term_string = {}
term_string['term'] = {}
term_string['term']["labels.Name"] = ""

for term in query_string.split():
    term_string['term']["labels.Name"] = term
    must_string.append(term_string)

query['query']['bool']['must'] = must_string

print(json.dumps(query))
```

I was expecting an output like this:

```
{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"term": {"labels.Name": "person"}}, {"term": {"labels.Name": "human"}}]}}}
```

but instead i'm getting this :

```
{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"term": {"labels.Name": "human"}}, {"term": {"labels.Name": "human"}}]}}}
```

**Note** the duplicated value in `labels.Name`.

There is a problem when I'm appending in the list and that's overwriting the previous value.

Comment: Mandatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending **the same dictionary** to your list each time. The reference is to one dictionary only. You can reference a new dictionary by constructing a new dictionary each time:

```
for term in query_string.split(): 
    term_string = {}
    term_string['term'] = {}
    term_string['term']["labels.Name"] = ""
    term_string['term']["labels.Name"] = term
    must_string.append(term_string)
```

For construction of a nested dictionary, I recommend you utilize `collections.defaultdict`: see [defaultdict of defaultdict, nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189274/defaultdict-of-defaultdict-nested).

Comment: So using collections.defaultdict it will be possible to directly assign values without initializing the variables ?

Comment: @user1297406, Exactly. See the link in my answer for an example.

Comment: Ok, got it,it works like a charm, here is my new code : [link](https://i.ibb.co/WFb20BR/python.png)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the list but the dictionnary : you update the value of

```
term_string['term']["labels.Name"]
```

at each iteration of your for loop. You could replace

```
term_string['term']["labels.Name"] = term
```

by something like:

```
term_string = {'term':{'labels.name':term}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries are passed by reference. Which means that when you append to `must_string` you are really appending a reference to the `term_string` dictionary, so that when you modify the term_string dictionary in the following loop it changes the underlying dictionary and not just the last version.

To get do what you want, you'll need to make a new dictionary for every loop to append, or you could do a `deepcopy()` (from the `copy` library) of your dictionary before you append it.