# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment while trying to create a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have several lists that im trying to iterate through and create a nested dictionary based off of a key(date in this case) . The lists are from a dataframe here's how am doing it but am getting the error above.
The idea is to get the values for 'total' and 'volume' for each type of bread for each date in the 'dates' list. The order of the lists is consistent and they have equal length. Any idea why this is happening?
The goal is to analyze/visualize the sales performance from 2018 to date
I have an idea that a nested dictionary might not be the best solutions so any better idea is welcome.

my data structure:

```
 ID      Created At                 Description                   Order No  Qnty StockID Price  Total  Date
233535  2020-05-30 19:12:17+03:00   SLICED ROUND TOP WHITE BREAD    71231   285 FG003   36.0    10260.0 2020-05-30
233537  2020-05-30 19:12:17+03:00   SLICED ROUND TOP BROWN BREAD    71231   15  FG004   36.0    540.0   2020-05-30
233529  2020-05-30 19:11:18+03:00   SLICED ROUND TOP WHITE BREAD    71229   90  FG003   36.0    3240.0  2020-05-30
233531  2020-05-30 19:11:18+03:00   SLICED ROUND TOP BROWN BREAD    71229   10  FG004   36.0    360.0   2020-05-30

breads=[]
dates=[]
volumes=[]
totals=[]
for i, row in sales.iterrows():
    bread=row[2]
    breads.append(bread)
    vol=row[4]
    volumes.append(vol)
    total=row[-2]
    totals.append(total)
    date=row[-1]
    dates.append(date)

from collections import defaultdict

sku_vol_total_by_date=defaultdict(dict)
for i in range(len(dates)):
    date=dates[i]
    bread=breads[i]
    volume=volumes[i]
    total=totals[i]
    if date not in sku_vol_total_by_date.keys():
        sku_vol_total_by_date[date]=date
        sku_vol_total_by_date[date][volume]=volume
        sku_vol_total_by_date[date][total]=total
    else:
        sku_vol_total_by_date[date][bread][volume]+=volume
        sku_vol_total_by_date[date][bread][total]+=total

sku_vol_total_by_date
```

Comment: At some point you have hit the of your dictionary (or list) nesting, and are treating a string as though it were a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the way you try to implement nested dictionaries.

First of all, you are using `sku_vol_total_by_date=defaultdict(dict)`, which is a defaultdict whose values are regular dicts, so you would not be able to use more than one nesting depth. However, there is a deeper problem with the way you use the dictionary.

Defaultdicts work by filling missing entries with a default value, based on the defaultdict's type, in your case, a dict. So the following will work, even though you never added an entry for the key "test":

```
sku_vol_total_by_date=defaultdict(dict)
print(sku_vol_total_by_date["test"])  # will print the empty dict {}
```

However, if you add a key/value pair manually to your defaultdict, it will use whatever value you supply:

```
sku_vol_total_by_date=defaultdict(dict)
sku_vol_total_by_date["test"] = "test_string"
print(sku_vol_total_by_date["test"])  # will print "test_string"
```

Since you explicitly add a string value to your dictionary, python will ignore the fact that you have defined the default value to be dict, and accept whatever you put into the dictionary.

The problem occurs when you start nesting. In the previous example, the dictionary contains a key/value pair `"test": "test_string"`.

So if you do this, it will fail with the error message you have given:

```
sku_vol_total_by_date["test"]["new_test"] = "new_test_string"
```

The expression `sku_vol_total_by_date["test"]` is the same as "test_string", so you are basically trying to write

```
"test_string"["new_test"] = "new_test_string"
```

And this is interpreted in python as something similar to `mystring[3] = "x"`, which is not allowed for strings.

So, where to go from here? Nested defaultdicts are described here: [Nested defaultdict of defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189274/nested-defaultdict-of-defaultdict)

Reading your code, I get the impression that nested dictionaries are not the solution to your problem though. It's hard to say what a good solution it without knowing exactly how your data is structured. I would assume that you want to group all the "volume" numbers that belong to the same "date", and do the same with the "total" numbers.

A hint to get you on your way, as this looks like a homework exercise and I don't want to give away the answer: grouping values can be done with a defaultdict(int), and you may need separate dictionaries for your "volume" and "total" values. Try to research some examples about defaultdicts and how they are usually used.

Comment: Thanks ,this is very informative. Actually its a work project am trying to analyze/visualize sales from 2018 to date and you are right i want to; have totals amounts and volume of sales for each date for each bread. I have a number of SKUs for bread so I could really use a hint to a better solution. I'm adding the structure of my data, thanks

Comment: The hint is: You can use more than one piece of data as a dictionary key by putting the data in a tuple (round brackets). Try putting date and bread type in the key together. Use one dictionary per value you want to accumulate (e.g. volume).