# Python3, building nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I'm new with Python, coming from Perl where I've used something like this very often:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
  
my %d;
my $a = 12; $b = 14; $c = 16;

$d{$a}{$b}{$c} = 42;

print($d{$a}{$b}{$c});  # 42
```

How can fill a dictionary in python e.g. in a loop

If I try this with Python, I've got a KeyError

```
a = 12
b = 14
c = 16

my_dict[a][b][c] = 42  # KeyError
```

Is this the only way?

```
if a in my_dict:
    if b in my_dict[a]:
        my_dict[a][b][c] = 42
    else:
        my_dict[a][b] = {}
        my_dict[a][b][c] = 42
else:
    my_dict[a] = {}
    my_dict[a][b] = {}
    my_dict[a][b][c] = 42
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a `dict()`, IMHO. It looks more like a multidimensional array instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries)

Comment: Your Perl code starts with an empty dict, your python code is explicitly built not to. Which case do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is actually better to use deafaultdict instead for this specific use case (it is a nested default dict inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19189356/8893827)):

```
from collections import defaultdict 

def nested_dict():
    return defaultdict(nested_dict)

my_dict = defaultdict(nested_dict)

a = 12
b = 14
c = 16

my_dict[a][b][c] = 42  # no KeyError
my_dict[a][b][c] 
>>> 42
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`dict.setdefault(key, default_value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, {}).setdefault(c, 42)
print(my_dict)  # {12: {14: {16: 42}}}

my_dict = {a: {}}
my_dict.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, {}).setdefault(c, 42)
print(my_dict)  # {12: {14: {16: 42}}}

my_dict = {a: {b: {}}}
my_dict.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, {}).setdefault(c, 42)
print(my_dict)  # {12: {14: {16: 42}}}
```