# Create a nested dictionary of arbitrary depth in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to create a dictionary where I can assign a value several layers deep inside the nested dictionary without explicitly creating the outer layers first. Here's what I'd like to be able to do:

```
d = {} # or whatever Python object works
d['a']['b']['c'] = 3
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

If I have a normal dictionary, I can assign a key like so:

```
d = {}
d['a'] = 1
```

but not like so:

```
d['a']['b'] = 2
```

However, I can use a `defaultdict` to do that like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(dict)
dd['a']['b'] = 2
```

However, I still can't do a deeply nested dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(dict)
dd['a']['b']['c'] = 3
```

I know I could do this with a recursive function but I was hoping there would be a simple way to do this. Is there?

EDIT:

I also tried this but it didn't work:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(defaultdict)
dd['a']['b']['c'] = 3
```

Comment: What use will you make of this?

Comment: You can use a nested default dict: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19189356/6759844

Comment: When you said you know you can do this recursively did you mean like `nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict); dd = nested_dict()` because that seems pretty

Comment: @Mark no, I hadn't thought of that. I like that approach

Comment: https://github.com/mewwts/addict

Answer (score 5):

You can use this, as a reference.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json
def recursive_dict():
    return defaultdict(recursive_dict)

x = recursive_dict()
x['a']['b']['c']=3
print(json.dumps(x))
```

Output:

```
{"a": {"b": {"c": 3}}}
```

Comment: This is so cool!!! Most of the defaultdict based replies only cater to a maximum two level dictionary.  This should be voted a lot more !!!! Thanks a lot. Saved my day

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to use a list of items as a dictionary's key.
Why don't you try with tuple? Cannot use a list as a dictionary's key.

```
d = dict()
d[('a')] = 1
print(d[('a')])
d[('a')] = 11
print(d[('a')])

d[('a', 'b')] = 2
print(d[('a', 'b')])
d[('a', 'b')] = 21
print(d[('a', 'b')])

d[('a', 'b', 'c')] = 3
print(d[('a', 'b', 'c')])
d[('a', 'b', 'c')] = 31
print(d[('a', 'b', 'c')])

d[('a', 'b', 'd')] = 32
print(d[('a', 'b', 'd')])
```