# Understanding nested defaultdict and `tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)` vs `tree = defaultdict(lambda: tree)`

Tags: python, tree, nested, trie, recursive-datastructures

### Working form

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189274/nested-defaultdict-of-defaultdict), I see how to create a defaultdict of defaultdict of defaultdict... as:

| Working form | Using it | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree) x = tree() ``` | ``` x["1"] x["2"] x["1"]["3"] print(json.dumps(x)) ``` | ``` {"1": {"2": {}}, "2": {}} ``` |

It works as desired, but I'm having trouble understanding it.

---

### Non-working form

Also, why does the following not work at all:

| Non Working form | Using it | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` tree = defaultdict(lambda: tree) x = tree ``` | ``` x["1"] x["2"] x["1"]["3"] print(json.dumps(x)) ``` | ``` ValueError: Circular reference detected ``` |

---

Can someone explain, how `tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)` works and why `tree = defaultdict(lambda: tree)` doesn't work?

---

EDIT: @Samwise notes in the comments that `tree` and each argument to `defaultdict` need to be callable, so to make the second form work, it'd need to be:

```
tree = lambda: defaultdict(lambda: tree())
```

but since `lambda: tree()` is equivalent to `tree`, this revised form is equivalent to the first form.

Comment: You'd want it to be `defaultdict(lambda: tree())` to produce the same result as `defaultdict(tree)`.  Otherwise the `tree` function itself never gets called.

Comment: In the second one, `tree` is one specific defaultdict, and the default values it uses are that same defaultdict. In the first one, each time `tree` is executed it will create a new defaultdict.

Comment: @Samwise, thanks. I tried `tree = defaultdict(lambda: tree())`, and in the next line `tree['a']` caused an error: `TypeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object is not callable`
`

Comment: You still need the outer `lambda` to make `tree` a function rather than a single `defaultdict` object.  So `tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)` works, as does `tree = lambda: defaultdict(lambda: tree())`.  `tree` and each argument to `defaultdict` need to be *callable*.

Comment: @Samwise gotcha, thanks! And since `lambda: tree()` is equivalent to `tree`, that means the longer form `tree = lambda: defaultdict(lambda: tree())` is equivalent to `tree = lambda defaultdict(tree)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
```

`tree` is a function, and each time it is executed, it creates a defaultdict. The default values of the defaultdict are given by calling `tree` again, which creates a new defaultdict each time.

---

Here:

```
tree = defaultdict(lambda: tree)
```

`tree` is one specific defaultdict. The default values of the defaultdict are given by a function that returns `tree`, the same specific defaultdict. So the default values of the dictionary are itself.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now! So with the second one. when I first do `tree['a']`, initially, `tree` does not have an 'a' key so it does 'tree['a'] = (lambda: tree)() = tree`. So after doing `tree['a']`, `tree` looks like `{'a': tree}`. If I then do `tree['b']['c']`, it will basically do `(tree['b'])['c'] = (tree)['c] = tree`, so now 'tree` looks like `{'a': tree, 'b': tree, 'c': tree}`.