# how do you build nested defaultdicts in Python with objects of a different type

Tags: python

I'm trying to rewrite the following code

```
dct = {}
x = 'x'
y = 'y'
z = 'z'
if x not in dct:
    dct[x] = defaultdict(dict)
if y not in dct[x]:
    dct[x][y] = defaultdict(dict)
if z not in dct[x][y]:
    dct[x][y][z] = defaultdict(list)
dct[x][y][z]['b'].append(defaultdict(int))
dct[x][y][z]['b'][0]['g']+=1
```

Without the following lines:

```
if x not in dct:
    dct[x] = defaultdict(dict)
if y not in dct[x]:
    dct[x][y] = defaultdict(dict)
if z not in dct[x][y]:
    dct[x][y][z] = defaultdict(list)
dct[x][y][z]['b'].append(defaultdict(int))
```

Ideally I would like to have syntax such as

```
dct = 'state what it is'
dct[x][y][z]['b'][0]['g']+=1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested defaultdict of defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189274/nested-defaultdict-of-defaultdict)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a customised implementation of `defaultdict` which can do this to an arbitrary depth, unlike the fixed depth from previous answers.

```
class DefaultDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, name):
        rval=type(self)()
        self.__setitem__(name, rval)
        return rval
```

Here's some example usage:

```
>>> dct=DefaultDict()
>>> dct[0][1]['bees'][('any','hashable','object')]=2
>>> dct[0][1]['bees'][('any','hashable','object')]
2
>>> 0 in dct
True
>>> 1 in dct
False
>>> dct
{0: {1: {'bees': {('any', 'hashable', 'object'): 2}}}}
```

Comment: @bobsmith76 This implementation works arbitrarily deep with all hashable objects

Comment: thanks i appreciate that.

Comment: It's also possibly worth mentioning that if you want to use `defaultdict` for some reason, you can either use the `tree=lambda:defaultdict:tree` from the linked question, but I dislike this for several reasons. (1) It's not anonymous, and so it's possible it could introduce bugs if you define another `tree`. A possible workaround is an anonymous class instance returning `self` in `__call__`, but that's untidy IMO. (2) It also doesn't allow for customisation based on the missing value, which may come in handy in future projects. This comment is mostly for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Use lambdas.

```py
from collections import defaultdict as dd

dct = dd(lambda: dd(lambda: dd(int)))

dct["foo"][1][("a", 7)] += 1
```

Comment: This doesn't go infinitely deep. I'm working on a solution which does.

Comment: Posted it in an answer below.