# KeyError while defining a new key value pair in a defaultdict created from an existing dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

Below is a sample code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

normal_dict = {
    "test": {
        "test1": 1,
        "test2": 2,
        "test3": {
            "test3_1": 1
        }
    }
}

default_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict), normal_dict)

default_dict['test']['test4']['test4_1'] = 1 # Doesn't work


print(default_dict)
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
KeyError: 'test4'
```

It seems like the previously non-existent key `'test4'` is not being automatically added when I use the line  `default_dict['test']['test4']['test4_1']`, for some reason. Theoretically, defaultdict should create the key `test4` with another defaultdict as its default value.

Comment: The problem is that the defaultdict creation rules don't convert your fixed dictionaries from normal_dict into defaultdicts.  If the initialization did try to coerce your input into its format then the ["test"]["test1"] would barf because 1 isn't a dict.  I bet if you try you will see that default_dict['testX']['test4']['test4_1'] = 1 does work.  And then if you just print(default_dict) you will see the difference between the 'test' entry and the 'testX' entry.

Comment: @Malcolm That makes sense. I guess the question now is how would you convert all the dictionaries inside `normal_dict` into defaultdicts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested defaultdict of defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189274/nested-defaultdict-of-defaultdict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Problem

The problem is that:

```
default_dict['test']
```

is:

```
{'test1': 1, 'test2': 2, 'test3': {'test3_1': 1}}
```

in other words is a dictionary not a `defaultdict`. Note that `defaultdict` provides a value (through the factory method) for a missing key, which is not the case at creation time in:

```
default_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict), normal_dict)
```

It won't copy the values and "transform" them to defaultdict.

#### One solution

One approach, that transform every nested dictionary into a defaultdict is the following:

```
def nested_dd():
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/19189356/4001592
    return defaultdict(nested_dd)


def convert_to_default(d):
    res = nested_dd()
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            res[key] = convert_to_default(value)
        else:
            res[key] = value
    return res


result = convert_to_default(normal_dict)

result['test']['test4']['test4_1'] = 1
pprint.pprint(result)  # need to import pprint
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<function nested_dd at 0x7fd27008bd90>,
            {'test': defaultdict(<function nested_dd at 0x7fd27008bd90>,
                                 {'test1': 1,
                                  'test2': 2,
                                  'test3': defaultdict(<function nested_dd at 0x7fd27008bd90>,
                                                       {'test3_1': 1}),
                                  'test4': defaultdict(<function nested_dd at 0x7fd27008bd90>,
                                                       {'test4_1': 1})})})
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert all the nested dictionaries inside `normal_dict` into default dictionaries?

Comment: @bravesheeptribe see the updated answer