# What's a clean way to use an object literal to track several (unknown) counts?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization, object-literal

Given the following code, there is the variable `counts` that counts the amount of times the function `functionThatGivesSomeKnownOrUnknownStatus` gives each status.

```
const counts = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const status = functionThatGivesSomeKnownOrUnknownStatus();

    counts[status] = counts[status] ? counts[status] + 1 : 1;
}
```

The part I don't like is this line `counts[status] = counts[status] ? counts[status] + 1 : 1;`, is there a way to make it shorter and simpler/less redundant/cleaner?
This is a node script so ES6/7 solutions are welcome.

One way could be initializing the `counts` literal with the keys already set to `0`, but I don't know the status the function can give.

---

*Tried to make the title as clear and concise as possible, if it can be improved, feel free to edit it.*

Comment: `counts[status] = (counts[status] || 0) + 1` saves one repetition.

Comment: A possible approach for more semantic is using a [default dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127650/defaultdict-equivalent-in-javascript) with value 0:

Comment: (Don’t implement a default dict with proxies like in the top answer to that question, though. It’s much cleaner to do it on top of `Map`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ry commented, I ended up using this solution:

```
counts[status] = (counts[status] || 0) + 1;
```

Inside the code:

```
const counts = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const status = functionThatGivesSomeKnownOrUnknownStatus();

    counts[status] = (counts[status] || 0) + 1;
}
```