# Is there a way to override Object to instantiate a property upon attempting to modify it?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I feel like the answer to this is a hard no in most languages I've used other than PHP, which at least used to have some odd corner cases with stuff like `$someArray['nonexistentKey']++`.

I'm basically looking to write a sparse object where each property is a numeric counter. The counters should return 0 if undefined and should automatically define themselves with a value of 0 if you try to increment them.

In other words, I want to override the generic Object getter to return `0` in all cases where it would return `undefined`... or perhaps define the property right there during the `get` and set it to `0`.

So in theory, an overload for ANY property not yet defined would `get` initialize it at zero. For example this:

`myObj['hugePrimeNumberToBaseXToString']++;`

would then make it 1.

In the olden days I feel like some way with `Object.__proto__` might have worked for this case...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defaultdict equivalent in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127650/defaultdict-equivalent-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

You can use a proxy to intercept property gets and return your own logic. In this case, return zero in the case of an `undefined` property.

```
// Hold the data
const target: { [key in string]: number } = {}

// Access the data
const proxy = new Proxy(target, {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
        if (typeof prop === 'string') {
            if (target[prop] === undefined) return 0
            return target[prop]
        }
        return undefined
    }
})

proxy['hugePrimeNumberToBaseXToString']++
console.log(proxy['hugePrimeNumberToBaseXToString']) //=> 1
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCGAnA5gUygLhgbxgbQGtUBPGASzBmkQuQF0swBXAWwCNVEYBfGAXhzwMARm4AoUJFgAHRCAAepAWFQB3GAAU5igBQIU6ADQ4xMMzDRQ9SS8dkhpxxKmCoyAN04BKE+b-kAMxg9YmlUECD7aX4+AQByalo4n2xTf3SyIOsDKDwouhiBJjAAE1QAilQSn2coJkRKAAY09L9a+sp9Szy5aToW-3FWmHaGmGKyipUSgfFuLzExe0U8OIALJjQtMhZUADlWDkQAFRAAIXgIVAANU4BlKBowZDi6AGo3iXAIEAAbVAAdL8QMgdMtiKsNlsaLsDuxOKcLldbiAHk8XnQfAB6LF8AB8MGEQA)

Comment: Whoa. I've been doing this for ages and written all kinds of gnarly ways to check if objects had been externally manipulated, short of object.watch(), and I didn't know you could do that at a fundamental level. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Proxy` is definitely the right answer, but I'd argue that tinkering with `Object` directly is much farther under the hood than you want to be.

Instead, I'd make a new, simple object type like so:

```
const Dictionary = function() {}

Dictionary.prototype.add = function(key) {
  if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    this[key] += 1;
  } else {
    this[key] = 1;
  }
}

const dict = new Dictionary();

dict.add("apples");

console.log(dict.apples) // 1

dict.add("apples");
dict.add("bananas");

console.log(dict.apples, dict.bananas) // 2, 1
```

It's not quite what you wanted since you have to call `add` each time, but I'd take the three-character tradeoff for the sake of simplicity and extensibility.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/wilson428/pen/dypmaaK)

Comment: I like this because it's AS3-like. Also answers the self-reference question but doesn't get to the immediate getter/setter of any property the way I was hoping for. Ultimately I was trying to create TypeScript classes like this that would accept only certain key types, so this could be a better way to go, because after messing around I don't think TypeScript allows you to extend Proxy in that way. Anyway thank you for the alternative answer. Good thought process here.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking along the lines of Python's [`.get`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) method for dictionaries, which allows for a default value if none exists -- would be trivial to precisely recreate that.